# Can we have dynamic property into @KafkaListener( propertyes = {max.pool.size.ms: ternary operator

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Is it possible to have dynamic ternary condition into @KafkaListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; see [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafkaIntegrationTests.java#L1723-L1728).

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "#{'qux'}", topics = "annotated4",
        containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "qux#{'Group'}",
        properties = {
                "max.poll.interval.ms:#{'${poll.interval:60000}'}",
                ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG + "=#{'${poll.recs:100}'}"
        })
```

In that case, it loads the `poll.interval` property and, if missing, uses 60000.

You can use any SpEL expression, e.g.

```
#{@someBean.someProperty}

#{'${foo.prop}' == null ? '${bar.prop:60000}' : '${foo.prop}'
```